# Android string-array: move strings out of array for better visibility

Tags: regex, android-studio

I have included a lot of [`string-array`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray) definitions in my Android strings resource file, like so:

```
<string-array name="my_items">
    <item>First Option</item>
    <item>Second Option</item>
    <item>Third Option</item>
</string-array>
```

Whilst this works fine, I'm finding that app localisation tools don't generally understand `string-array` definitions, which makes it a pain to export strings for translation.  Even the Translation Editor in Android Studio seems to ignore these `string-array` definitions.

So what I want to do is to move the strings themselves out of the array, where they have better visibility, and reference those from inside the array, like so:

```
<string name="my_items_1">First Option</string>
<string name="my_items_2">Second Option</string>
<string name="my_items_3">Third Option</string>

<string-array name="my_items">
    <item>@string/my_items_1</item>
    <item>@string/my_items_2</item>
    <item>@string/my_items_3</item>
</string-array>
```

Since I have a LOT of these (in several language resource files), I'm looking for some way of doing this conversion/mapping in an automated fashion.  I'm thinking maybe there may be a very cunning regexp-based solution, involving lookaheads or lookbehinds, and or suchlike.  I am hopeless with regexp, so I'm not sure it this is possible.  If not, maybe there is a script-based method?

Hoping for some inspiration from someone!

Comment: did the answer work for you ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to know which file contains the pattern mentioned above... once you know the files that should be taken care of then you apply the following, the code is written in java7 as you are not going to do it over android phone... rather you need it for development context therefore think the following code as a tool to modify files as you desired :

as a safety precaution, Make sure you have backup of your files before you exceute the follwoing code

```
package regex;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import static java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes;
import static java.nio.file.Paths.get;

/**
 *
 * @author Maverick
 */
public class Regex {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


        final String regex = "<string-array name=\\\"(.*?)\\\">(.*?)<\\/string-array>";
        String string = null;
        string = new String(readAllBytes(get("G:/sample.xml")));
        final String subRegex = "(<item>)(.*?)(<\\/item>)";
        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
        final Pattern subPattern = Pattern.compile(subRegex, Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
        Matcher submatcher;

        String str1 = "", str2 = "";
        String finalResult = "";

        while (matcher.find()) {
            submatcher = subPattern.matcher(matcher.group(2));
            str1 = "";
            str2 = "<string-array name=\"" + matcher.group(1) + "\">\n";

            int j = 0;
            while (submatcher.find()) {
                j += 1;
                str1 += "<string name=\"" + matcher.group(1) + "_" + j + "\">" + submatcher.group(2) + "</string>\n";
                str2 += "<item>@string/" + matcher.group(1) + "_" + j + "</item>\n";
            }
            str1 += "\n\n";
            str2 += "</string-array>\n\n";

            finalResult = str1 + str2;
            string = string.replace(matcher.group(0), finalResult);
        }
        File myFoo = new File("G:/sample.xml");
        FileWriter fooWriter = new FileWriter(myFoo, false);
        fooWriter.write(string);
        fooWriter.close();


    }
}
```

**Content of sample.xml before the execution:**

```
<string-array name="my_items1">
    <item>First Option1</item>
    <item>Second Option1</item>
    <item>Third Option1</item>
</string-array>

asdfadsf
safasdfadsf

<string-array name="my_items1">
    <item>First Option1</item>
    <item>Second Option1</item>
    <item>Third Option1</item>
</string-array>

sdfasfasdf

<string-array name="my_items12">
    <item>First Option12</item>
    <item>Second Option12</item>
    <item>Third Option12</item>
</string-array>

aa
basfad

<string-array name="my_items13">
    <item>First Option13</item>
    <item>Second Option13</item>
    <item>Third Option13</item>
</string-array>

afsdfadsf
```

**After Execution**

```
<string name="my_items1_1">First Option1</string>
<string name="my_items1_2">Second Option1</string>
<string name="my_items1_3">Third Option1</string>


<string-array name="my_items1">
<item>@string/my_items1_1</item>
<item>@string/my_items1_2</item>
<item>@string/my_items1_3</item>
</string-array>



asdfadsf
safasdfadsf

<string name="my_items1_1">First Option1</string>
<string name="my_items1_2">Second Option1</string>
<string name="my_items1_3">Third Option1</string>


<string-array name="my_items1">
<item>@string/my_items1_1</item>
<item>@string/my_items1_2</item>
<item>@string/my_items1_3</item>
</string-array>



sdfasfasdf

<string name="my_items12_1">First Option12</string>
<string name="my_items12_2">Second Option12</string>
<string name="my_items12_3">Third Option12</string>


<string-array name="my_items12">
<item>@string/my_items12_1</item>
<item>@string/my_items12_2</item>
<item>@string/my_items12_3</item>
</string-array>



aa
basfad

<string name="my_items13_1">First Option13</string>
<string name="my_items13_2">Second Option13</string>
<string name="my_items13_3">Third Option13</string>


<string-array name="my_items13">
<item>@string/my_items13_1</item>
<item>@string/my_items13_2</item>
<item>@string/my_items13_3</item>
</string-array>



afsdfadsf
```